# SpriteKit physics giving different results each time

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, game-physics

In my game I'm creating some balls which are effected by gravity. When game starts they fall from out of screen and get their places at the bottom. No other force is applied to them.

The problem is I'm creating these balls with exact coordinates, exact physics attributes like previous one but the result is not the same. It is similar but not same. But I think it should be exactly the same because in every time the values are same.

You can understand what I've said in these 3 pictures below.[image][image][image]

Do you have any idea why this is happening? How can I solve it?

This is how I create the sprite nodes:

```
BallSpriteNode *sprite = [BallSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:ballTexture];
sprite.xScale = scale;
sprite.yScale = scale;
sprite.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:sprite.size.width/2];
sprite.physicsBody.density = 1.0f;
sprite.physicsBody.restitution = 0;
sprite.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
sprite.physicsBody.categoryBitMask =  ballHitCategory;
sprite.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = ballHitCategory;
sprite.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = ballHitCategory;

CGPoint startPosition = CGPointMake(xPosition, yPosition);
sprite.position = startPosition;

[bounceScene addChild:sprite];
```

Comment: If you want exact result each time don't let physics engine to determine what should happen. Take a control in your own hands. Means, disable physics engine until you place objects at their initial positions. Then, use SKActions to move objects where appropriate. After that, you can re-enable physics bodies on those objects, and you are good to go.

Comment: It's not an option for me I've multiple levels and in each level different set of balls order. I can't do it for every different situation. Physics should behave consistently.

Comment: So where is the problem ? Make an array of starting positions for each object (or define a CGPoint per ball which represent its starting position). You can't rely on physics engine in the way you want.

Comment: Why can't I rely on I couldn't understand it. I have my positions and I want them to fall. It is not logical to move the ball to desired location for every different situtation. Also it's not the same as falling effect.

Comment: The physics library is optimized for speed, not accuracy. The reason why your physics is different is because a different amount of force is applied each time, due to the update refresh not being constant.  The first time you run, the code may have taken 1/60th of a second,  the second time, it may have taken 1/60.0000000000001 of a second, thus having a different force value due to that extra tiny bit of time

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of factors involved in making a physics engine less random.

The FPS greatly affects the randomness. In SKSpriteKit Physics, you have a Update method in the SKScene, which is called once every frame and carry the time difference from the previous frames. Usually to make it less random you have to somehow override the method.

Or use other Physics engine's which are customisable (Bullet Physics). It is very easy to get same result by only adjusting the StepSimulation function call.